# Aliasing in the Short time Fourier Transform of a pulse

Tags: fourier-transform, stft

When attempting to take the Short Time Fourier Transform of a pulse, at the end of the pulse I'm running into problems.

The signal looks like this at the end (it is a simple $sin^2$ pulse envelope, with a carrier frequency $\omega$.  The only frequency that I care about in the STFT is $\omega$):

[image: signal]

And when I perform a STFT on it using a flattop window of $6 * 2\pi/\omega$ width (and only look at the carrier frequency):

[image: stft signal]

The error here for the STFT seems abnormally large towards the end.  When I look at the difference between the envelope ($A * sin^2(\frac{ t * \pi }{ T} )$ where A is fitted by hand to minimize the error  in the center of the pulse) and the absolute value of the STFT produced signal, I get something that looks like this:

[image: error]

The two lobes at the end are what the problem is.  Does anyone have any sources that discuss this source of error?  Properties, how to mitigate them, etc?

Comment: Can you try using another window and see if you still get the lobes?

Comment: Are you doing a deconvolution with the window function before you compare it to the original function?

Comment: @DanielShapero:  Other flattop windows give similar results.

Comment: @user7257:  I'm not sure exactly what you are talking about.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: What I'm assuming you are doing is overlapping FFTs with windowing.  The last plot in your post is your error, comparing the reconstructed signal with the original signal, yes?  If so you need to compensate for the influence of the window function first.

Comment: @user7257:  I believe that the windowing function used (a flattop from `scipy.signal`) should reproduce the amplitude very well, however there seems to be a problem near the end of the signal related to the pulse.  The only compensation I can think of is a constant factor, which I ignored by hand fitting the amplitude of a $sin^2$ envelope to the reconstructed signal.  Is there some other compensation that I need to do?  If so, can you point me to a reference?